# How to use LiveView in C# webform to display some fields vertically and some horizontally within in one table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, listview, webforms

My SQL Server table has these fields:
- Name
- Score
- Month

I need to create a ListView (in C# webform) that can display the data like this:

[image]

So the Name and Score are in vertical, the Month (1-12) om horizontal.

Do I also need to use some JavaScript?

any references or tutorials I may get a head start?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called **Pivot Table** where you can manipulate some of your data columns into rows in conjunction to the rest of your data columns.

Take a look at this [JQuery Pivot](http://plugins.jquery.com/pivot/), its a jquery plugin that might help you achieve what you want.

Comment: Hi Samer, what if I also need to edit any values of Name or Score?

Comment: My original goal is to create textboxes for all Name values and DropDownLists (from 1 to 100) for all Score values;
so 12 textboxes and 12 dropdownlists.

Comment: then when the user clicks a Submit button, the data will be stored into the database.

Comment: You need to customize then, I am not sure to what degree you can customize on the plugin I gave you.

Comment: You can also try to do it manually, you get the data and loop over the values to draw them as columns then loop again to draw the data you need as rows, of course you can put what ever you want to wrap the data such as inputs (textboxes), give that a try.

Comment: do you have example references for looping? do it manually is probably the best way for me.

Comment: I found a possible reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx but not sure I to implement the textboxes or dropdownlist.